# Regex to replace anything in quotes with an empty string:

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
string CName = "My name "cool" sunny";
```

I want to remove "cool" from CName.
Expected output should be
CName = "My name sunny"

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one string to remove from the whole string ?

Comment: I don't know C# well, but is this even valid syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to replace anything in quotes with an empty string:

```
string CName = "My name \"cool\" sunny";
string newCName = Regex.Replace(CName, "\".*\"", "").Replace("  ", " ");
```

Comment: `string newCName = Regex.Replace(CName, "\s*\"[^\"]*\"\s*", " ");` removes the quoted fragment and doubles (white)spaces in one go

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to delete "cool", try [String.Replace Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1) to replace `"cool"` with empty string.

If you want to remove anything between `""`, you can try [Regex.Replace Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netcore-3.1).

Here is the demo.

```
string CName = "My name \"cool\" sunny";
Regex reg = new Regex("\".*\" ");
CName = reg.Replace(CName, "");
```

Comment: `"\"[^\"]*\""` pattern will be a safier choice, esp. if you have several fragments to remove: `"my \"actual\" name \"cool\" sunny"`